# Is git merge origin master same as git merge origin/master?

Tags: git, github

Is `git merge origin master` the same as `git merge origin/master`. If not how is it different? the objective is to merge the latest remote master to a local branch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not the same at all. `git merge origin/master` will merge your remote-tracking branch `master` to your current head. `git merge origin master` will attempt to create an octopus merge with branches `origin` and `master` to the current head. It will probably fail, because most likely you do not have a branch named `origin` (which would be very confusing, since it is the default name for a remote repository).

Use `git merge origin/master`.

Answer (score 2):

Merging the latest from `master` as it is in `origin` right now is a 2-step process.

- Fetch
- Merge

This can be done in different ways. The step-by-step one is

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

There are some things you can do to *automate* this process somewhat. One of them is to setup `origin/master` as the *upstream* branch of the local branch you are dealing with... something like `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master`).... then you can do

```
git pull
```

`git pull` takes care of running the fetch and then merging.

Another way, if you haven't set the upstream branch is to do

```
git pull origin master
```

Which does the same thing: fetch, merge.